# Can this DAO method be simplified?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, coding-style

This is how I learned (on the job) to create a class, create a database access object with a readRecord method in order to get information from the database.  What I'm curious about, is what the SF community's recommendations would be for shortening it?  I could get rid of a few lines of code by moving the readRecord code up into the DAO method and just changing it up in there, but that still presents the problem of having possibly hundreds of lines of codes...just for properties in a class, and for getting the values for those properties in the DAO.

I understand that there's nothing really to do in the class (I mean, you can't just auto-generate a bunch of properties...Visual Studio doesn't know what I'm going to make!), but for the DAO, is there a way to loop through all properties in the class, determine their types, and then get the information?  I abhor typing hundreds of "property = dr.GetVariableType("variablename");" over and over again!

Sorry for the code length...I copied the properties 6 times to give an idea of what I'm talking about.

Class

```
namespace MySoftware
{
    public class User
    {
            public int userId { get; set; }
            public string userName { get; set; }
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
            public string MI { get; set; }
            public string suffix { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string phone{ get; set; }
            public string SSN { get; set; }
            public int roleId { get; set; }
            public bool IsTemp { get; set; }
            public int userId { get; set; }
            public string userName { get; set; }
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
            public string MI { get; set; }
            public string suffix { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string phone{ get; set; }
            public string SSN { get; set; }
            public int roleId { get; set; }
            public bool IsTemp { get; set; }
            public int userId { get; set; }
            public string userName { get; set; }
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
            public string MI { get; set; }
            public string suffix { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string phone{ get; set; }
            public string SSN { get; set; }
            public int roleId { get; set; }
            public bool IsTemp { get; set; }
            public int userId { get; set; }
            public string userName { get; set; }
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
            public string MI { get; set; }
            public string suffix { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string phone{ get; set; }
            public string SSN { get; set; }
            public int roleId { get; set; }
            public bool IsTemp { get; set; }
            public int userId { get; set; }
            public string userName { get; set; }
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
            public string MI { get; set; }
            public string suffix { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string phone{ get; set; }
            public string SSN { get; set; }
            public int roleId { get; set; }
            public bool IsTemp { get; set; }
            public int userId { get; set; }
            public string userName { get; set; }
            public string firstName { get; set; }
            public string lastName { get; set; }
            public string MI { get; set; }
            public string suffix { get; set; }
            public string email { get; set; }
            public string phone{ get; set; }
            public string SSN { get; set; }
            public int roleId { get; set; }
            public bool IsTemp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

DAO

```
namespace MySoftware
{
        public static List<User> GetUsers(int departmentId)
        {
            List<User> user = new List<User>();

            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection conn = ConnectionHelper.GetConnection("connectionString"))
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetUsers", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptId", departmentId);
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            users.Add(readUserRecord(dr));
                        }
                    }

                    return users;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to get users", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then I read the record (this is normally located at the bottom of the DAO.

```
    public static User ReadRegRecord(SqlDataReader dr)
    { 
        User user = new User();

        user.userId = dr.GetInt32("Id");
        user.userName = dr.GetString("UserName");
        user.schoolId = dr.GetInt32("schoolId");
        user.roleId = dr.GetInt32("roleId");
        user.Active = dr.GetBoolean("Active");
        user.IsTemp = dr.GetBoolean("IsTemp ");
        user.firstName = dr.GetString("firstName");
        user.MI = dr.GetString("MI");
        user.lastName = dr.GetString("lastName");
        user.suffix = dr.GetString("Suffix");
        user.email = dr.GetString("email");
        user.Phone = dr.GetString("Phone ");
        user.SSN = dr.GetString("SSN");
        user.userId = dr.GetInt32("Id");
        user.userName = dr.GetString("UserName");
        user.schoolId = dr.GetInt32("schoolId");
        user.roleId = dr.GetInt32("roleId");
        user.Active = dr.GetBoolean("Active");
        user.IsTemp = dr.GetBoolean("IsTemp ");
        user.firstName = dr.GetString("firstName");
        user.MI = dr.GetString("MI");
        user.lastName = dr.GetString("lastName");
        user.suffix = dr.GetString("Suffix");
        user.email = dr.GetString("email");
        user.Phone = dr.GetString("Phone ");
        user.SSN = dr.GetString("SSN");
        user.userId = dr.GetInt32("Id");
        user.userName = dr.GetString("UserName");
        user.schoolId = dr.GetInt32("schoolId");
        user.roleId = dr.GetInt32("roleId");
        user.Active = dr.GetBoolean("Active");
        user.IsTemp = dr.GetBoolean("IsTemp ");
        user.firstName = dr.GetString("firstName");
        user.MI = dr.GetString("MI");
        user.lastName = dr.GetString("lastName");
        user.suffix = dr.GetString("Suffix");
        user.email = dr.GetString("email");
        user.Phone = dr.GetString("Phone ");
        user.SSN = dr.GetString("SSN");
        user.userId = dr.GetInt32("Id");
        user.userName = dr.GetString("UserName");
        user.schoolId = dr.GetInt32("schoolId");
        user.roleId = dr.GetInt32("roleId");
        user.Active = dr.GetBoolean("Active");
        user.IsTemp = dr.GetBoolean("IsTemp ");
        user.firstName = dr.GetString("firstName");
        user.MI = dr.GetString("MI");
        user.lastName = dr.GetString("lastName");
        user.suffix = dr.GetString("Suffix");
        user.email = dr.GetString("email");
        user.Phone = dr.GetString("Phone ");
        user.SSN = dr.GetString("SSN");
        user.userId = dr.GetInt32("Id");
        user.userName = dr.GetString("UserName");
        user.schoolId = dr.GetInt32("schoolId");
        user.roleId = dr.GetInt32("roleId");
        user.Active = dr.GetBoolean("Active");
        user.IsTemp = dr.GetBoolean("IsTemp ");
        user.firstName = dr.GetString("firstName");
        user.MI = dr.GetString("MI");
        user.lastName = dr.GetString("lastName");
        user.suffix = dr.GetString("Suffix");
        user.email = dr.GetString("email");
        user.Phone = dr.GetString("Phone ");
        user.SSN = dr.GetString("SSN");
        user.userId = dr.GetInt32("Id");
        user.userName = dr.GetString("UserName");
        user.schoolId = dr.GetInt32("schoolId");
        user.roleId = dr.GetInt32("roleId");
        user.Active = dr.GetBoolean("Active");
        user.IsTemp = dr.GetBoolean("IsTemp ");
        user.firstName = dr.GetString("firstName");
        user.MI = dr.GetString("MI");
        user.lastName = dr.GetString("lastName");
        user.suffix = dr.GetString("Suffix");
        user.email = dr.GetString("email");
        user.Phone = dr.GetString("Phone ");
        user.SSN = dr.GetString("SSN");
        return user;
    }
}
```

For instance, is there a way to do something like this for the DAO/readRecord?
(I know this doesn't work, but if someone can think of something similar, I'd love to hear it).

```
        foreach (var prop in student.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (prop.PropertyType == "String")
            {
                prop.Value = dr.GetString(prop.Name.ToString());
            }
            if (prop.PropertyType == "Int")
            {
                prop.Value = dr.GetInt32(prop.Name.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: You've discovered one reason why ORMs exist

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What's the SF community?

Comment: This question should be on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into an ORM such as the [Entity Framework](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/).

If for whatever reason those don't suit your needs, I'd suggest looking into writing a [T4 Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx) so you can generate the exact data access code you need. T4 is an extremely powerful and underutilized tool in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a typical pattern:

1. Use EF to generate classes that map to existing database tables
2. Use Automapper to automatically map properties with the same name and/or apply custom mapping logic such as normalization

That saves you the grunt code of mapping DataReader columns to entity properties.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty good to me the way it is. Of course one can argue that there are tools to abstract away this work from you, but since you wanna do it, that's how I would do it.

If you want something that can remove that burden from you, you could use [DapperDotNet](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) or NHibernate/EF for a more bloated solution.

With Dapper your DAO would look like this:

```
public static List GetUsers(int departmentId)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = ConnectionHelper.GetConnection("connectionString"))
        {
            return conn.Query("GetUsers", new { DeptId = departmentId }).ToList();            
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to get users", ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (off the top of my head):

```
foreach (var prop in typeof(User).GetProperties())
{
    prop.SetValue(student, dr[prop.Name]);
}
```

assuming that the names of all the properties correspond to names in the data reader, and that any values coming from the data reader can be coerced into their corresponding properties (which is one good reason to use an ORM, as others have noted in answers and comments).

You might also have to check for `DBNull` values. Since `SqlDataReader`'s `IsDBNull` method only takes the integer of the column index, and not the column name, you'll have to use `GetOrdinal` to find out which column position corresponds to each name:

```
foreach (var prop in typeof(User).GetProperties())
{
    object val;
    if (dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal(prop.Name))) {
        val = null;
    } else {
        val = dr[prop.Name];
    }
    prop.SetValue(student, val);
}
```